# Calculated value in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table that has 4 column that needs to be calculated to get the average value. I know how to get the average value. 
What I don't know how to do is to get get that value to show on another column on another table. How do I do that?

Example:

```
Columns:   ID Size1 Size2 Size3 Size4 
Values:    1  92    82     63    83
```

I know how to get the average value from that, but I need to know how a column in another table can refer to that average value. I am using PHPMyAdmin

Comment: you need to use `join` statement. Show other table schema.

Comment: Do you mean the result in a query or to update a column?  Please modify the question to clarify your desired results.

Comment: I mean to update a column. If the Size column are null the result will also be null on the column I want the value to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

Has stated in the comments if you just need this as a query result a join will do.

```
Select t1.ID,t2.ID,(T1.Size1 + T1.Size2 + T1.Size3 + T1.Size4) / 4 as Avg
From t1 join t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

This assumes that T1 is table one (has sizes) and T2 is the second table in which you have the other values that you want to add average to.

Now lets assume you want an avg column in another table to be tied to rows in your T1 (sizes) table.  To do this you can use a trigger.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER AvgValues
ON T1
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO T2(Avg)
     SELECT (T1.Size1 + T1.Size2 + T1.Size3 + T1.Size4) / 4
     FROM T1
     WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
END
```